# How to put elements side by side like media player using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've worked with bootstrap grid system and tables but unable to do this kind of template... putting elements side by side and top bottom kind of things. Please help me how to do?

Please give related tutorials or posts or any jsfiddle or any stuff I'm a beginner.

here is the template image:[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div id='miniPlayerID'>
     <div  class="row" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;background-color:#2D87BA;margin:0px">

            <table width="100%">

    <col width="10%"/>
        <col width="20%"/> 

            <col width="10%"/>
                <col width="10%"/>
                    <col width="10%"/>
                        <col width="40%"/>

                    <tr><td>
                    <img src="img/Album.png"  class="img-responsive" id="clickedMiniPlayer" style="width:90%;margin-left:5%;"/>
                    </td><td>
                    <p class="text-justify" id="miniplayerPlayTitle" >Mirchi Mirch</p>
                    </td>
                        <td>
                    <center>                        
                        <img src="img/bakward.png" class="img-responsive zoom-img" id="previousClickedMiniPlayer" style="width:50%;margin-left:5%;"/></center>
                    </td>
                        <td>
                    <center><img src="img/play.png" class="img-responsive zoom-img" id="playClickedMiniPlayer"  style="width:50%;margin-left:5%;"/></center>
                    </td>
                        <td>
                    <center><img src="img/forward.png" class="img-responsive zoom-img"  id="nextClickedMiniPlayer" style="width:50%;margin-left:5%;"/></center>
                    </td><td>
                        <center><input type="range"  min="-50" max="0" id="miniPlayerVolumeID"></input></center>
                    </td>
                        </tr>
    </table>
 </div> </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code and more information about what you have done so far.

Comment: Provide us with the code you already made.

Comment: @n2o and Davey D my code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are allowed to use bootstrap for your grid?

A possible solution could look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src=""> <!-- place your image here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <!-- title -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        Yahin hoo main...
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- your buttons -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        rewind
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        play
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        forward
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- bar -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        |----*------------------|
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't have to use a table in your code, because you can also use the bootstrap grid to align your track-information.

I "guessed" the correct distribution of the 12 elements of the grid and assigned 3 parts to the image and 9 for the rest. You might have to adjust these parameters and test it in your code.

[The bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) provides many information and examples. You will find all answers to your problem in this documentation ;-)

Comment: Thank you n20 for you kind help, but its not responsive its not adaptive to all layouts

Comment: It is responsive as you can read in the bootstrap documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options. You can adjust your behavior for even smaller devices in using `col-sm-x` and others instead.